# NewtonSoft JsonConvert deserialize on dynamic object type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an abstract object Item that has several children: RadioItem, CheckItem, etc.

Each item stores its own properties in a serialized JSON string property.

I'm trying to make a static class that can take in an Item, instantiate a new item from the JSON string and return that.

Right now I have the code looking something like this:

```
public static Item GetFreshItem(Item dirtyItem)
{
    string itemProperties = dirtyItem.InitialItemSettingsJSON;

    if (dirtyItem is RadioItem)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RadioItem>(itemProperties);
    }

    if (dirtyItem is CheckItem)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckItem>(itemProperties);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a way to not have a long list of If (x is Type) and use a more dynamic single return statement depending on the type that was passed in?

I was thinking it'd be something like this (which doesn't work)

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeOf(dirtyItem)>(itemProperties);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`(string, Type)` overload](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) of the deserialize method.

```
string itemProperties = dirtyItem.InitialItemSettingsJSON;
return (Item)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(itemProperties, dirtyItem.GetType());
```

Comment: That definitely looks like the ticket.  Just to make sure though, casting/returning it as an item I'd still have access to all of the RadioItem Properties once it's returned (assuming I cast it as such later).

Comment: Yep! That's how it differs from `DeserializeObject<Item>`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
public static T GetFreshItem<T>(T dirtyItem) where T:Item
{
    string itemProperties = dirtyItem.InitialItemSettingsJSON;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(itemProperties);
}
```

This way you don't need a cast.